# Auto choice of Spring annotation in IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, annotations

I have to add for example *@Trancient* annotation to my project by auto-replace some parts of my code. So now I have 100+ such annotations in 50+ files of the code.

During compilation IDEA  **every time asks** me what exact annotation I would like use from: javax.persistence OR javax.beans OR ...

Is there any way to **tell my IDE** what exact package for annotation to use so it can auto-import them all?

Comment: You can try [excluding other variants from the imports](http://i.imgur.com/jvsx0Bo.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes. That's good. Answer will be accepted if published. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the imports you don't need in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `General` | `Auto Import`, **Exclude from Import and Completion**:

[image: exclude]

You can also exclude directly from the import popup by selecting the import you don't need and pressing the **right arrow** to open the submenu, then select the variant to exclude and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: exclude popup]

The main problem here is to not forget to remove the excluded class from the list if you plan to use it later.